# Possible to publish tkinter web app on the internet?

Tags: python, tkinter, web-applications, pycharm, weather-api

I made a weather web application using tkinter library. However whenever i am trying to publish it on github pages or other web hosts, it get 404 error.

I tried pythonanywhere by anaconda as well and still couldn’t publish my application

Comment: Why do you want to publish your tkinter application on a web host? Web applications are usually built on Django, Flask, etc. Do you want to make a working demo that other people can try out?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to publish the app so anyone could use it.

Comment: I assume that you don't want to convert your tkinter application to an executable for end users (which is the usual way to distribute desktop applications). As long as you don't mind using repl.it for demo purposes, you don't need real hosting. Alternatively, you can create a GitHub repository to demonstrate your code and add a video of how your app works (screen recording).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tkinter isn't designed to work on a website. With a tremendous amount of engineering it might be possible, or by using third party websites*. At its core, though, tkinter requires a display, not a browser.

* repl.it makes it possible to run tkinter code, though I don't think it's suitable for making apps. It's good for experimentation, though. I've seen one or two other solutions for running tk on the web, but they are very specialized and generally don't let you create apps that work like a traditional.

Answer (score 0):

You could try CloudTk. This will run an X11 app (like Tkinter) on a Linux host running VNC and display it via noVNC in a web browser. Check out CloudTk at
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/CloudTk and for examples of Tcl/Tk apps (which could be any X11 app as all the examples are run in Docker Containers) go to https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Showcase